# Access to Windows notification from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, notifications

How to get access to Windows notification from WPF?

I tried this way.  I got `accessStatus` allowed.

But i get the exception
`System.Exception: 'Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)`

Here is my code:

```
using Windows.UI.Notifications.Management;
***
public partial class NotificationWindow : Window
    {
        UserNotificationListener listener;
        public NotificationWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SubscribeToNotif();
        }

        public async void SubscribeToNotif()
        {    
            listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
            
            UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = await listener.RequestAccessAsync();

            if(accessStatus == UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed)
                listener.NotificationChanged += Listener_NotificationChanged;
        }

        private void Listener_NotificationChanged(UserNotificationListener sender, Windows.UI.Notifications.UserNotificationChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got notif");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
Add `WPF` project to `Windows Application Packaging Project`

Comment: Having the same issue, using net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0 adding WPF to WAPP, didn't solve it for me :(.

Comment: I resolved my issue, in my case it was my windows machine, it must have something modified so that any call to the listener will cause "Element not found", tested on another machine the exception is gone there.

Comment: Well steam3d ... could you enlighten me please as to how I can achieve this with a Windows Application Packaging Project?  Do I use .NET 3.1 or .NET 6.0 i my WPF app?  And do I use Windows.SDKs ?  Any snippets and/or clues would be most appreciated Thanks

Comment: Add Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts to your WPF project.  Add a new Windows Application Packaging Project and add to it the WPF project and use my code above it will work